# Join tables with Aggregate value

Tags: sql-server, join

I've two tables, named Table-A and Table-B. Please refer given tables . I want to join these after taking the aggregate of 'Value' column in both tables. For eg;

**TABLE-A**

```
     Name    Value1
      ABC     10
      ABC     18
      ABC     12
      DEF     5
      XYZ     15
      XYZ     16
```

**TABLE-B**

```
     Name    Value2
      ABC     15
      ABC     5
      XYZ     9
```

My expected result is,

**Result**

```
     Name    Value1   Value2
      ABC      40       20
      DEF      5        0
      XYZ      31       9
```

Hope you understand my question. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      a.Name
    , Value1 = ISNULL(Value1, 0)
    , Value2 = ISNULL(Value2, 0)
FROM (
    SELECT 
          Name
        , Value1 = SUM(Value1)
    FROM dbo.[TABLE-A]
    GROUP BY Name
) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
          Name
        , Value2 = SUM(Value2)
    FROM dbo.[TABLE-B]
    GROUP BY Name
) b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: You've missed the GroupBy clause and distinct. Anyway it will not work for my case. Can you please test with sample.

Comment: Yea, i got that. Thanks. But is there any possibility with only join statements. I mean, without using temporary tables.

Comment: That's the best and efficient way to do that, thank you @Devart

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [TAB-A].NAME, VALUE1, VALUE2 FROM
(SELECT NAME, SUM(VALUE1) VALUE1 FROM [TABLE-A] GROUP BY NAME) [TAB-A] LEFT JOIN
(SELECT NAME, SUM(VALUE2) VALUE2 FROM [TABLE-B] GROUP BY NAME) [TAB-B]
ON [TAB-A].NAME = [TAB-B].NAME
```

Comment: +1 for the good answer. but please replace in your query `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
      COALESCE(A.Name, B.Name)
    , (CASE WHEN A.value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE A.value END) AS Value1
    , (CASE WHEN B.value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE B.value END) AS Value2 
FROM (
    SELECT Name, SUM(Value) AS Value 
    FROM #A GROUP BY Name
) AS A 
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT Name, SUM(Value) AS Value 
    FROM #B GROUP BY Name
) AS B ON A.Name = B.Name

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason for dropping those tables. Anyway it works and Thanks.

Comment: I had the following code before:
create table #A
(
 Name nvarchar(255)
 ,Value int
)
create table #B
(
 Name nvarchar(255)
 ,Value int
)

insert into #A
select 'ABC',10 union all
select 'ABC',18 union all
select 'ABC',12 union all
select 'DEF',5


insert into #B
select 'ABC',15 union all
select 'ABC',5 union all
select 'XYZ',12

Comment: Devart & Pavel: Should be full outer join not left join: because if you switch the data in the table you will lose data, and isnull or coalesce should be apply to a.name and b.name